# Promise.all returns double array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

In my node Router I have the following:

```
router.get("/single-base/:id", (req, res) => {
Base.find({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then(bases => {
        let basefetches = [];

        for (let base of bases) {
            basefetches.push(BaseUser.find({ baseId: req.params.id }));
        }
        return Promise.all(basefetches).then(users =>
            res.json(users.map(user => user.serialize()))
        );
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    });
});
```

when console logging `return Promise.all(basefetches).then(users => console.log(users))` I receive:

```
[ [ { created: 2018-08-27T21:37:42.151Z,
  _id: 5b846f268cb4481264298f82,
  userId: 'tester2',
  baseId: 5b81528e1314da25bc498085,
  acceptedMembership: false,
  isCreator: false,
  __v: 0 } ] ]
```

I have the exact same method in another place, and it returns only an empty array (this array should be empty in the beginning as well). 
Why/when/how is this pushing an array into another array, how do I solve this so that the `users.map` does not throw:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
at Base.find.then.bases
```

**EDIT**: I believe this has to do with the `BaseUser.find({})` method. When console logging: `Promise.all(basefetches).then(users => console.log(users));` I get the following:

```
{ created: 2018-08-25T12:43:02.640Z,
  _id: 5b81528e1314da25bc498085,
  creatorId: 5b7efd4db3036a13601ad8d7,
  title: 'testBase1',
  __v: 0 }
[ [ { created: 2018-08-27T21:37:42.151Z,
      _id: 5b846f268cb4481264298f82,
      userId: 'tester2',
      baseId: 5b81528e1314da25bc498085,
      acceptedMembership: false,
      isCreator: false,
      __v: 0 } ] ]
```

I

Comment: `res.json()` doesn't take an argument. It returns a promise, you need `res.json().then(<function>)`

Comment: @Barmar: He's using Express' `res.json()`, not Fetch's `res.json()`.

Comment: @Barmar `app.use(express.json());` I omitted that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MongoDB data. And if `BaseUser.find()` uses [MongoDB's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) `db.collection.find()`, then it returns a cursor (hence the conversion to array at this level I guess).

If the `baseId` is intended to be unique (i.e. you expect one result at the most), you might want to use `db.collection.findOne()` instead.

However, I don't understand why you wrap

> `basefetches.push(BaseUser.find({ baseId: req.params.id }));`

in a loop over `bases`, since `bases` is not used at all in the loop. Seems like you just repeat the exact same query yielding the exact same result for as many `bases` as you got.

Anyway: one array because of `find()`, and one because of the promises-slash-loop-over-`bases`.